# Oracle trigger to insert value from another table in a cycle

Tags: oracle

In tableA I have an ID field that I want to be a value from tableB when inserting into tableA. It should however cycle through all values in tableB for each record entered. So if I have id's in tableB of 0, 1, 2, 3 then on first insert to tableA it would assign tableB value 0, on 2nd insert it should use tableB 1, then 2, then 3, then back to 0, and just loop in a cycle like this.

I'm guessing I'd need a table to track which one should be the next value and then in my trigger use that value then get the next value to use for the next insert trigger. Would there be any other ways that someone can think about doing this outside of a stored proc?

Comment: It will be very easy to understand with actual table data n structure?

Answer (score 0):

From what I have understand is you trying to load the data from TableB into TableA looping through IDs from TableB. 
If the data in TableB is historical data that you want to load it on to TableA, then you need stored procedure with cursor inside so that you can do initial delta load from B to A. you dont need another table here in that case since you are using Cursor in Stored Procedure.

If you want TableA to be populated when there is an insert or update on TableB then you can use trigger on TableB.

Comment: So basically this is a way to assign a server name (stored as a field in tableB) (not really randomly but by just looping over them) into new records that get created in tableA. Imagine tableA stores jobs/tasks to run and it has a field to tell it what server to run that task on and tableB is a list of available server names. I want to just assign sequentially the next server in the list for each insert into tableA. When I reach the end I want to go back to the beginning server name and start over.